# What is the release Date of Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)?

Tags: release-management

What is the exact release date of Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail?

Comment: I don't know why this was closed. It's a well defined question with a canonical answer. Re-opened!

Comment: @Oli isn't it off topic, because it is asking about a non-released version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Gui +1 isn't inherently off-topic. *Issues* with +1 are off-topic.

Comment: @Oli oh okay, I wasn't sure, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Wiki says it's evening.

Answer (score 23):

### Update: [Available](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/)

#### April 25, 2013

According to the [Release Schedule.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseSchedule)

Comment: I was talking to the developers last night on a separate issue.  Its expected to come out on time (25th April)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Ubuntu Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseSchedule), Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail will be released on April 25 2013.

If you want you can download beta 2 of Raring [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-13.04-beta-2), although 13.04 will not be supported on this site until it is released.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu site
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
You can find realeses and end of life of ubuntu distribiutions.